# Using SharePoint to access and modify data in database

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, development

I have a situation where I currently have a huge spreadsheet that is used for tracking 40+ deliverables for projects. The spreadsheet solution is past cumbersome.

I have been thinking about how I can use our SharePoint instance to handle some of these tasks. One option that I have been thinking about was to create a relational database (MSSQL) and then use SharePoint to access and modify the data. I would like to be able to grant users access to specific data elements to allow users to modify the data rather on depending on an administrative resource. This will require some development.

I am relatively new to working with SharePoint so there must be some better ways to implement this functionality rather than the typical list functionality. Right now I am looking for some ideas and this is the best place to find them.

Thank you in advance.
Ray

Answer (score 1):

You could use SharePoint Business Connectivity Services. That way you could hook up the SQL Server tables to SharePoint lists.